# Python - Deleting a sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, xlutils, pyexcel

Is there any function that has been made to delete only a single sheet using xlwt, xlrd, xlutils, xlutils.filter, or pyexcel? Those are the only ones I have access to and I want to know how to delete a sheet.

Perhaps you could create a list with all the sheet names, remove the sheet name from that you want to delete, and then copy every sheet name from that list and then save the workbook with the original name.

Any help is useful!

Comment: nick, what have you tried so far?  Does Google give you any leads?  I see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569456/editing-existing-excel-workbook-using-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils?rq=1) listed to the right in the "Related" list --- does it have anything that helps you?

Comment: That doesn't really help me but thanks anyways

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an existing worksheet in excel file using xlutils, xlwt, xlrd with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085755/how-to-delete-an-existing-worksheet-in-excel-file-using-xlutils-xlwt-xlrd-with)

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried that and it keep coming up with an error. Plus it only removes all other sheets except the sheet in the bracket not just one sheet

Comment: pyexcel removes the formatting, not a good choice for your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that was given on the other question was this:

```
write_book._Workbook__worksheets = [write_book._Workbook__worksheets[0]]
```

This removes everything but the first worksheet associated with a Workbook.